# Count re-Occurrence of a string - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

What method is best to count the following, Each line is a string created by a loop.

```
Jane
Jane
Matt
Matt
Matt
Matt
Jane
Paul
```

In the end i would like to know : Jane = 3, Matt = 4, Paul = 1. Would i use an array or a loop ?

Comment: How is this stored as a result - in a single string? Or this is just an output of a loop?

Comment: Its the result from a loop after a sql lookup.

Comment: @MattLeyland If it is from SQL, use a `count` and `group by` to get the result from the query.

Comment: @JohnKoerner - I am using Sql ATM for testing but it more than likely change to a text file/csv later that we have to read in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a List(Of String) e.g.

```
Dim arr As New List(Of String)
```

And inside of your loop collect your strings:

```
arr.Add(CurrentString)
```

After the loop `arr` would have all the strings. Then you can run a simple LINQ query:

```
Dim Summary = From a In arr Group By Name = a Into Group _
              Select Name, Cnt = Group.Count()
```

This Summary will give you the counts. You can use it for example

```
For Each elem In Summary
    'Output elem.Name
    'Output elem.Cnt 
Next
```

For your example this will produce

```
Name = "Jane", Cnt = 3 
Name = "Matt", Cnt = 4
Name = "Paul", Cnt = 1
```